# Why is UIActionSheet transparent when presented?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiactionsheet

My `UIActionSheet` is transparent when it displays. How do I change this? here's a screenshot of what the problem looks like:

[image]

the code:

```
   - (IBAction)btnTakePicture_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Image from..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Image Gallary", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    actionSheet.alpha=0.90;
    actionSheet.tag = 1;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    intButton = btn.tag;
}
```

Comment: If you don't include the code you use to generate the action sheet, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella ok, code added. thanks! I thought it may have been a common problem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what's causing problems is

```
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Probably in iOS 7 this causes the transparency. Try removing it.

Also you are setting the alpha to 0.9, which will cause some transparency in any case (not as showed in the screenshot though). If you want a completely opaque action sheet, remove also

```
actionSheet.alpha=0.90;
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the lines:

```
 actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
 actionSheet.alpha=0.90;
```

Should do the trick